# Virtualbox fullscreen mode stops working after update

Tags: virtualbox

I got Ubuntu 14.04 installed in VirtualBox. I installed the guest additions and GNOME 3, and everything was working.

Now, Ubuntu's software manager popped up and notified me that updates were available, so I installed them. I restarted the system and now two things have started to happen:

1. Fullscreen has stopped working *View -> Switch to fullscreen*.
2. I am getting a memory error sometimes when shutting down. The status under the Virtualbox manager is reporting that the process of shutting down the system was aborted.

Has anyone else had this problem after installing the OS updates? I've been looking around the forums, but I cannot seem to find anything that is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem.  Here are my notes on how I resolved it. It comes from the vbox manual [chapter 4](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) paragraph 4.2.2.1

> Be sure to install DKMS before installing the Linux Guest Additions.
>   If DKMS is not available or not installed, the guest kernel modules
>   will need to be recreated manually whenever the guest kernel is
>   updated using the command /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup as root.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

Answer Y to question.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the help, just what I needed.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  I do occasionally still get the memory error on shutdown, but it does not seem to do any harm.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install all the guest additions packages from the repositories, that way each time you perform an kernel update, the corresponding modules will be automatically recreated:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-x11
```